# Retrieve Format of a NotesViewColumn

Tags: xpages, lotusscript, xpages-ssjs

Is there a way to find out which format applies to a NotesViewColumn?  I can see that there are a number of format attributes e.g. DateFmt, TimeDateFmt, NumberFormat etc, but what I can't see is a way to identify which one of them applies.

Answer (score 0):

Combine your current column's value type with NotesViewColumn's format attributes.

If your current column value is of type **number** then use
NotesViewColumn's **NumberFormat, NumberAttrib, NumberDigits** format.

If your current column value is of type **NotesDateTime** then use
NotesViewColumn's **DateFmt, TimeDateFmt, TimeFmt, TimeZoneFmt** format.

Comment: Does that rely on accessing the data?  I was hoping to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I think so. Although you can define only one data format at a time in view's column it stores all formats. NotesViewColumn class has no property "dataFormat" or so.

Comment: Notes has no schema, so a column doesn't really have a data type, per se. It has a 'Style' for formatting - and there is no Style property in the NotesViewColumn class. Anyhow, even if you do look at the data, you can't be sure that the selected Style really matches the type of that data. In most cases it probably does, but it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to read NSF design, you could rely on DXL export to get the information needed. Try the DXL utility on *Tools - DXL Utilities - Viewer*:

[image: Tools -> DXL Utilities -> Viewer]

As you may find, the piece of information you need is nested inside every `<column>` node.

For number columns there is a `<numberformat>` node.

For time columns there is a `<datetimeformat>` node above `<numberformat>`.

For text columns there is nothing.

In case you need to programaticaly analyse a number of views, there is the **NotesDXLExporter** on hand.